# Rank nodes on type in JointJS in combination with Dagre

Tags: jointjs, dagre

I would like to know if/how it is possible to rank nodes depending on a certain type. So lets say Dependend I want to align on the same level as the current node and child below and parent above.

Is this possible? I use Dagre now to align my nodes but I want to be a bit more in controll.

Kind regards,
kevin